# How to get Full path from fileupload mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

its look different than asp.net File upload
and i can get the full path from it
but 
  How to get Full path from fileupload mvc4 inside my controller ?

Comment: what are you intending on doing the full path?? what code have you currently used? Show some code.

Comment: i've simple view that contain (input type="file") and Model like
ID --- int "  path--- string that's all and offcourse my controller